# Additional data members in Eloquent Collection not being copied

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, deep-copy

I have extended the basic `Eloquent\Collection` class as follows:

```
class BoogerCollection extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {

    // Metadata used by my collection
    protected $some_array = [];

    public function setArray(){
        $this->some_array = [1,2,3];
    }

    public function getArray(){
        return $this->some_array;
    }
}
```

So, the following works as expected:

```
$collection = new BoogerCollection();
$collection->setArray();
print_r($collection->getArray());   // Prints out Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

However, if I then perform some operation on the collection which returns a modified copy of the collection, this metadata gets lost:

```
// Perform some operation on the collection that makes a copy
$collection = $collection->reverse();
print_r($collection->getArray());      // Prints out Array ( )
```

So, my `$some_array` member is not getting copied.  I dug into the code for `Eloquent\Collection` and `Support\Collection`, and it looks like these methods all create new Collections by directly constructing them from the Collection's internal representation of the items:

**in Eloquent's `Support\Collection`:**

```
public function reverse()
{
    // $this->items is the Collection's internal representation of the collection of items
    return new static(array_reverse($this->items));
}
```

Does this mean that to have my metadata array copied as well, I must override every single method?

Answer (score 0):

Extending `Eloquent`'s `Collection` class doesn't mean it will be used by `Eloquent` to return a collection of models. For now, `Eloquent` will stick with it's `Collection` class, which is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` when returning a collection. If you look at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`'s codes, you'll see the methods that returns a collection (`get()`, `findMany()`, etc.) will call the supplied model's `newCollection()` method which in turn returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and not your newly created subclass.

Your code: `$collection = new BoogerCollection();` works because you're the one who instantiated your class. But when doing something like `MyModel::all()` won't return your `BoogerCollection` class as `Eloquent` will be the one to choose what `Collection` class it wants to return and right now it sticks with `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.